# How can i add a path to this URL via user input?

Tags: c++

Trying to prompt the user to type their username on this instagram link so that it will open on their profile, how can I add the username to this line of code?

```
string UName;
        cout << "For this option please enter the Username" << endl;
        cin >> UName;
        ShellExecute(0, 0, L"https://www.instagram.com/UName" , 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
```

Output should be instagram website of the username

Comment: You should be able to use the `std::string`'s `+` operator, although you may need to convert `UName` to a `std::wstring` first.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I have never used std::wstring

Comment: `wstring` is a wide-character version of `string`. `L"my string"` is a wide-character version of a C-style string. I believe you'll need to use `wstring`'s `+` operator to work with wide-character string literals. Also, consider using `wcin` rather than `cin`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` has an [`operator+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) for concatenating a `char char*` with a `std::string`, returning a new `std::string`.  You can call [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) on that `std::string` when passing it to `ShellExecuteA()` (not `ShellExecuteW()`), eg:

```cpp
string UName;
cout << "For this option please enter the Username" << endl;
cin >> UName;
string url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + UName;
ShellExecuteA(NULL, NULL, url.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `+` after insta url ends then `+` add by using this.
`"url/"+username`

Comment: I tried that but got a syntax error, not too familiar with ShellExecute attribute